# Next JS + Image optimization

Tags: reactjs, image, optimization, next.js

I've got this ticket thats asking me to "frond-end optimize image size, dimension, quality from code"

the images are user uploaded in binary format? and I retrieve them + load them on the page using the API link they give me for that page.

Image size, dimension and quality -> I can set dimensions easily, change the images from jpeg to png where needed like such

```
        <img
          src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${
            data.images ? data.images[0].imageData : ""
          }`}
          className={styles.headerImage}
        />
```

But what else can I do for images?

Is it possible to crop images on the front end before setting it as say - a mobile or tablet bg picture?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization

Comment: Don't convert it to base64, just pass the source URL to `next/image`. It will change the format to `webp` which is more efficient than JPEG and PNG. Also the cropping thing that you are referring will be done, i.e. on mobile a smaller resolution image will be loaded. Please refer the link shared by Alexander above.

Comment: Im using Static Export + Client side data fetching = no node server running. (We use IIS to host the site) so next/image isn't available for me.

Comment: @TigerCode you can always use [`next-optimized-images`](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images) instead. It optimizes the images during the build process. [This issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18356) somewhat covers all the alternatives.